# how come it doesn't matter where i put if (savedInstanceState != null){} in onCreate method

Tags: android, android-activity

Let me show you 2 examples of my code.

```
example 1:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
        };
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    }
```

example 2:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {             
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    };
}
```

I'm wondering how come it doesn't matter where I put

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){
    mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
};
```

in my code. My hypothesis was that `setContentView` displays the current layout, which is  different if `mCrrentIndex` is changed. So it would matter if I FIRST set the content view and THAN check what int does the `mCurrentIndex` have. It turns out thats not the case and I don't know why. Could anyone explain?

Comment: You must set bundle first, if you want use it later. Look at [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) method.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState method is allready implemented in other parts of code. The question is why the if statement can be before or after senContentView method. (both ways work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onCreate` method, no views have yet been created, they are inflated at a later stage of the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). So when they are loaded, the new value of `mCurrentIndex` will be used, since even if you set it after you call `setContentView`, it is still *before* any views have been created.